# How to get data from upwork using upwork api without Login in php?

Tags: php, upwork-api

I have upwork api. I am getting the data after login and i need to set cron job but unable to set the cron because api always redirect to login page. So Everytime user has to autheticate with the registered account of that specific user.  So Is there anyway to fetch data from upwork api without login in php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According `[RFC 5849][1]`, you need to login at least once to grant the access to the requested data for your application.

Once you receive an access token/secret pair, you can reuse them in the next requests (just make sure you keep them in a safe place/storage). That said, you don't need to call authorization screen on every request and can setup a cron job.